# Do I need to fill in my tax declaration in Germany?

Tags: income-tax, germany

Almost everywhere it is stated that if I am single and an salaried employee without additional income I do not need to present my tax declaration.

However, I have read in a couple of places (for example, my company's onboarding page) that, if any give year I decide to present it, I need to keep doing it the following years. I did present it last year.

I don't know what I should do. The draft says that I would have to pay 3€ (plus the software fee). I will present them anyway just to have peace of mind, I would like very much to know the answer.

Comment: As German (who is in the group who have to file taxes, and has been in the group for whom it is volountary) this question doesn't make sense to me: OP's employer has to give them all information OP requires for their income tax declaration, regardless of whether OP files or not, and at no fee. (There are some situations where you have a choice, e.g. VAT for small businesses for whom it is volountary, where you are bound for a certain number of years, but AFAIK not for income tax)

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX I have all tax information, but my company does not give advice beyond that. The fee is for the software that I use to fill the tax declaration and send it electronically, because it is easier for me.

Comment: Don't spend money on tax software if your case is simple. Try the Tax Office's online service https://www.elster.de/ . I guess it has everything you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your only income is through normal, full-time employment at a single job and your tax bracket is "Steuerklasse 1" you do *not* explicitely need to declare your taxes in Germany.

Your tax bracket is automatically set at "Steuerklasse 1". You can only change it if you sign forms and depending on new tax bracket provide documentation that you are eligable. So if you are single and don't really know, then your tax bracket *is* "Steuerklasse 1". They don't grant you a cheaper one "just because" or somehow on accident.

What "Steuerklasse 1" means is that your employer sends the maximum amount of taxes to the tax authorities *automatically*. You don't ever see that money in your account. Your employer only pays into your account what is left *after taxes* (... and after health care and after social). This way, the tax authorities already got the maximum they can get from you *up front*.

Taking that into account, the tax authorities are happy as pie if you do not declare your taxes. They already *got* what they want. The maximum amount. Only if you want a refund for something, you actually need to declare your taxes.

Now lets assume you bought something that is deductable. For example, if you commute to work, that is deductable. If you want that money back, you need to fill out a tax declaration to announce that they got the maximum but you were eligable to pay less and with the attached proof they should give you a refund.

You can do that for one year and not for the next and nobody will ask. For example if you commuted 2019 and filled out a tax declaration to get a refund, but then COVID hit and you worked from home and get no refund for 2020, then you just do nothing for 2020. You are not required to explicitely file, as long as you have "Steuerklasse 1". Filing one year does not change that for the next year. I mean otherwise, how would it ever stop? If filing one year automatically means you have to file the next, too? That is not how it works.

---

That said, obviously you *do* have to declare taxes explicitely if you have more income than just your job. Lets say you own 5 houses and rented them out. Then you need to declare that, even though you have "Steuerklasse 1" because that money did not go through an employer and was not automatically taxed.

And yes, if you declare to have 5 houses you rent out in 2019, the tax authorities *will* ask you what happened to them in 2020 if you just not file. Because the houses did not vanish into thin air and the tax authorities are suspicious of you trying to defraud them. As they should be.

But as long as you hold a single job and have "Steuerklasse 1" and only file because you want some money back... then you only have to file in those years where you want money back.

From personal experience I can tell you that tax authorities in Germany have never been more silent and forthcoming than in years I was single and employed and I did not file my taxes and they got to keep the maximum amount they are entitled to. They don't rock the boat if they got your money already.